# Extracting average time series

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, json

I have this JSON code that I got from a get request with Azure API. Everything works how I want it but it doesn't look good. There must be an easier way to parse the data.

```
import json
#GET REQUEST code here, it works now the code below is grabbing the result and loading it.
formatted_response = {'cost': 0, 'timespan': '2020-07-07T03:00:00Z/2020-07-07T03:15:00Z', 'interval': 'TM', 'value': [{'id': '/subscriptions/hjhkjhjljkjknlkjjlkj/Groups/jhkjhjkhjs/providers/Micro/virtualMachines/jhjkhkjhjkhkhljkl/providers/MicInsights/metrics/Percentage CPU', 'type': 'Microsoft.Insights/metrics', 'name': {'value': 'Percentage CPU', 'localizedValue': 'Percentage CPU'}, 'displayDescription': 'The percentage of allocated compute units that are currently in use by the Virtual Machine(s)', 'unit': 'Percent', 'timeseries': [{'metadatavalues': [], 'data': [{'timeStamp': '2020-07-07T03:00:00Z', 'average': 2.4659375}, {'timeStamp': '2020-07-07T03:01:00Z', 'average': 2.974375}, {'timeStamp': '2020-07-07T03:02:00Z', 'average': 2.90265625}, {'timeStamp': '2020-07-07T03:03:00Z', 'average': 1.72484375}, {'timeStamp': '2020-07-07T03:04:00Z', 'average': 1.1275}, {'timeStamp': '2020-07-07T03:05:00Z', 'average': 0.05640625}, {'timeStamp': '2020-07-07T03:06:00Z', 'average': 0.05515625}, {'timeStamp': '2020-07-07T03:07:00Z', 'average': 0.055}, {'timeStamp': '2020-07-07T03:08:00Z', 'average': 0.28765625}, {'timeStamp': '2020-07-07T03:09:00Z', 'average': 0.0546875}, {'timeStamp': '2020-07-07T03:10:00Z', 'average': 0.054375}, {'timeStamp': '2020-07-07T03:11:00Z', 'average': 0.05734375}, {'timeStamp': '2020-07-07T03:12:00Z', 'average': 0.0553125}, {'timeStamp': '2020-07-07T03:13:00Z', 'average': 0.05609375}, {'timeStamp': '2020-07-07T03:14:00Z', 'average': 0.0528125}]}], 'errorCode': 'Success'}], 'namespace': 'Microsoft/virtualMachines', 'resourceregion': 'eastus8'}

p = formatted_response['value']

for i in p:
    for j in i:
        if j == 'timeseries':
            q = i[j]
for l in q:
    for u in l:
        if u =="data":
            g=l['data']

for r in g:
    for s in r:
        if s == "average":
            print(r[s])
```

```
$ python testapi.py
2.4659375
2.974375
2.90265625
1.72484375
1.1275
0.05640625
0.05515625
0.055
0.28765625
0.0546875
0.054375
0.05734375
0.0553125
0.05609375
0.0528125
```

Comment: @Peilonrayz Added the output of formatted response above the picture so the code could be tested that way, but now I just put it up top instead so you can run the whole snippet. I just ran it in my terminal and it gave me the output.

Comment: Ok so `formatted_response` was the value not `formatted_response['value']` like you had originally said. Yes this outputs the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Json should be put in a separate file.**

*myfile.json*

```
{   "cost":0,
   "timespan":"2020-07-07T03:00:00Z/2020-07-07T03:15:00Z",
   "interval":"TM",
   "value":[      {         "id":"/subscriptions/hjhkjhjljkjknlkjjlkj/Groups/jhkjhjkhjs/providers/Micro/virtualMachines/jhjkhkjhjkhkhljkl/providers/MicInsights/metrics/Percentage CPU",
         "type":"Microsoft.Insights/metrics",
         "name":{
            "value":"Percentage CPU",
            "localizedValue":"Percentage CPU"
         
},
         "displayDescription":"The percentage of allocated compute units that are currently in use by the Virtual Machine(s)",
         "unit":"Percent",
         "timeseries":[            {               "metadatavalues":[

               
],
               "data":[                  {
                     "timeStamp":"2020-07-07T03:00:00Z",
                     "average":2.4659375
                  
},
                  {
                     "timeStamp":"2020-07-07T03:01:00Z",
                     "average":2.974375
                  
},
                  {
                     "timeStamp":"2020-07-07T03:02:00Z",
                     "average":2.90265625
                  
},
                  {
                     "timeStamp":"2020-07-07T03:03:00Z",
                     "average":1.72484375
                  
},
                  {
                     "timeStamp":"2020-07-07T03:04:00Z",
                     "average":1.1275
                  
},
                  {
                     "timeStamp":"2020-07-07T03:05:00Z",
                     "average":0.05640625
                  
},
                  {
                     "timeStamp":"2020-07-07T03:06:00Z",
                     "average":0.05515625
                  
},
                  {
                     "timeStamp":"2020-07-07T03:07:00Z",
                     "average":0.055
                  
},
                  {
                     "timeStamp":"2020-07-07T03:08:00Z",
                     "average":0.28765625
                  
},
                  {
                     "timeStamp":"2020-07-07T03:09:00Z",
                     "average":0.0546875
                  
},
                  {
                     "timeStamp":"2020-07-07T03:10:00Z",
                     "average":0.054375
                  
},
                  {
                     "timeStamp":"2020-07-07T03:11:00Z",
                     "average":0.05734375
                  
},
                  {
                     "timeStamp":"2020-07-07T03:12:00Z",
                     "average":0.0553125
                  
},
                  {
                     "timeStamp":"2020-07-07T03:13:00Z",
                     "average":0.05609375
                  
},
                  {
                     "timeStamp":"2020-07-07T03:14:00Z",
                     "average":0.0528125
                  
}
               
]
            
}
         
],
         "errorCode":"Success"
      
}
   
],
   "namespace":"Microsoft/virtualMachines",
   "resourceregion":"eastus8"
}
```

*myfile.py*

```
with open("myfile.json") as file_obj:
    formatted_response = json.load(file_obj)
```

**Use descriptive identifiers for variables.**

```
formatted_response_value = formatted_response['value']
```

**Unnecessary double for loop**

```
formatted_response_value = formatted_response['value']
timeseries = formatted_response_value[0]["timeseries"]   #please name something descriptive at all places. 
data = q[0]["data"]
average = list(map(lambda x:x["average"], g))[-1] #or [entry["average"] for entry in g][-1]
```

Comment: Is there a way I can avoid the for loops? it seems excessive.

Comment: Yep, I was thinking of nested filters. But I 'm trying to understand your code

Comment: Thank you! I will make the fixes.

Comment: Ask me if you got any confusion without any hesitation.

Comment: Please upvote the answer if you like it.

Comment: Thanks:) . Use of map, filter can cut down your loops.

Comment: Will do in future. Thanks.